# Update Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am just update xcode(10.0) after update i was update as well as  swift language version(4.2) but  middle in progress of updatation swift language give me some error i really confused how to solve this:

**Error:**

> **Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey'**

```
@objc(imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) func  imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo Info: [String: Any]){
    let mediatype = Info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
    if mediatype.isEqual(to: kUTTypeImage as String) {
        let imagecopy = Info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        profileImage.image = imagecopy
        if newpic == true {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imagecopy, self, #selector(imageError),nil)
        }
    }
     self.dismiss(animated:true,completion:nil)
     onlyUploadImage()
}
```

**Error Screen Shot**

[image: Screen Shot]

Can someone please explain to me how to solve this , i've tried to solve this issue but no results yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate function has beed changed. Now it is

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
```

And You can get information from info dictionary as following

```
info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaType]
```

and

```
info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Replace Your

`func  imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo Info: [String: Any]) {}`

with

`func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {}`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because of changes in Swift 4.2 version.

Use this code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    if let originalImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        print(originalImage)
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```